# Javamail exception in maven project

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail

I am using javamail to send an automatic e-mail. Its working fine when I run it in indivitual java project. But when I copy pasted same classes in large maven project it gives mefollowing error. I tried hard but unable to find whats going wrong. Please suggest.

```
    Debug Log:-
    DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
    DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
    DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
    DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port 465, isSSL true
    220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
    DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port: 465

    EHLO
    501 5.5.4 Invalid argument
    HELO
    501 5.5.4 Invalid argument
    javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 5.5.4 Invalid argument

Done
Testing Complete , Check Inbox Please
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1363)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.helo(SMTPTransport.java:838)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:375)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at com.yahoo.cvp.impl.utils.DQMErrorHandlingEmail.sendMail(DQMErrorHandlingEmail.java:47)
    at com.yahoo.cvp.impl.utils.EmailDemo.main(EmailDemo.java:14)
```

When I run it in individual java project its successful and gives following log.

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7

DEBUG: getProvider() returning 

javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]

DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false

DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready

DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port: 465

EHLO 10.0.0.36

250-smtp.mail.yahoo.com

250-PIPELINING

250-SIZE 41697280

250-8 BITMIME

250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XYMCOOKIE

DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""

DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "41697280"

DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8", arg "BITMIME"

DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN XYMCOOKIE"

DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 

DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed

DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded

DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false

MAIL FROM:<ankursjoshi16@yahoo.com>

250 OK , completed

RCPT TO:<ankurjoshi16@gmail.com>

250 OK , completed

DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses

DEBUG SMTP:   ankurjoshi16@gmail.com

DATA

354 Start Mail. End with CRLF.CRLF

From: ankursjoshi16@yahoo.com

To: ankurjoshi16@gmail.com

Message-ID: <1020328935.0.1402817158491.JavaMail.javamailuser@localhost>

Subject: Indoors Readable File:

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h1>This message is from Indoor Positioning App. Required file(s) are attached.</h1>
.
250 OK , completed

QUIT

221 Service Closing transmission

Done
Testing Complete , Check Inbox Please
```

Comment: found [this](http://brianoneill.blogspot.com/2009/04/invalid-arguments-501-554-error-when.html) and [this](http://dzone.com/snippets/authenticate-smtp-server) Please have a look at :)

Comment: You're also using different versions of java mail. It doesn't work from 1.4ea (ea stands for early access, so it's some kind of beta version), while it does work with java mail 1.4.7. Try upgrading the dependency in you maven project to the latest version of java mail 1.x.

Comment: wow thanks guys .. Now I want to exclude geronimo-activation_1.1_spec from pom.xml. I know which dependency in pulling it.
xyz.xyz.xyports_org_apache_cxf__cxf_rt_ws_addr.
When I look in mvn dependency:tree there are lot of +,-,/ are there under this entry. I included exclusion just below main mentioned entry but it didn't work , where should I put exclusion ?

Comment: The latest version of JavaMail is [1.5.2](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).